# Loravel framework mcrypt missing

Tags: apache2, php

Just created a loravel project using composer but when trying to enter 127.0.0.1/loravel/public is says mcrypt is missing.

I already tried everything I could find. My `mcrypt.ini` already is in `mods-available`

Tried to install `php5-mcrypt`, already exists. Tried to install again, didn't work.

I use Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Answer (score 2):

To enable php5-mcrypt in apache do

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```